# Can I access a variable set on a Coldfusion page in a template I'm loading, if not using session scope?

Tags: templates, variables, coldfusion, global-variables, scope

I have a Coldfusion8 page, in which I'm declaring some variables upfront like so:

```
<cfif (structKeyExists(url,"extern"))>
    <cfset variables.someVar = "value">
<cfelse>
    <cfset variables.someVar = "">
</cfif>
```

Following this I have a number of templates, which I'm loading:

```
<cfinclude template="templates/tmp_pagetop.cfm">
<cfoutput><head></cfoutput>
<cfinclude template="templates/tmp_pageheader.cfm">
...
```

I'm having trouble accessing my *variables.someVar* inside my template.

**Question:**
Is this at all possible using the *variables* scope? I don't want to use *session* or *application* scope, because the variables I'm dealing with should actually only exist in the respective page. But I thought it would be possible to declare once in the page and reference throughout the templates. If I can't use variables, is there another way?

**EDIT:**
First up, thanks for all the feedback!

When I started using SO, I usually put up questions like below, but ended up cutting down to the bare minimum, as I usually didn't get an answer on thourough questions... pity...  I guess I may be leaving too much away :-)

So, if anyone wants to take a look, I have a page called search.cfm. This page is a shell page into which I'm loading different layouts through AJAX and/or templates. Specific case was the search form loaded via AJAX.

So this is 3 parts:

**1) search.cfm** Here I'm checking Session.extern(al) for local instances of the page. If it's a local instance I grab the users variabels A,B,C which I had hoped to access when loading in the search form template.

```
<cfif (structKeyExists(url,"extern"))>
    <!--- preload external user data  --->
    <cfstoredproc procedure="proc_select_extern" datasource="dtb">
        <cfprocparam type="in" value="#Session.extern#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" maxlength="13">
        <cfprocresult name="external_user">
    </cfstoredproc>

    <!--- set external variables --->
    <cfif external_user.recordcount eq 1>
        <cfoutput query="external_user">
            <cfscript>
            // CULPRIT string
            variables.user_modules = external_user.modules;
            </cfscript>
        </cfoutput>
    <cfelse>
    <!--- remove unknown URL params --->
        <cfset StructDelete(Session, "Extern")>
    </cfif> 
</cfif>
```

Then in my **app.js** I'm listening for the ([Jquery-Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html)) pagebeforeshow event and load the respective form into the page via AJAX:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#search' , function(e, data) {
    // load main search form
    if ( $(this).attr('val') != true ) {
        $(this).attr('val') == true;
        // here I'm calling the default search form
        ajaxUpdate( "../layouts/tmp_searcher.cfm", $('.searchFromWrapper'), "search", "default", "search" );
        }
....
var ajaxUpdate = 
    function update( from, target, param, account, bindings ) {
        $.mobile.loading( 'show' );
        $.ajax({
            async: true, type: 'GET', returnFormat: 'json', 
            data: { value: param, type:  account },
            url: from, timeout: 7500,
            success: function(data) {
                var makeUp = !$.support.touch ? data.replace("<select", "<select data-native-menu='false' ") : data;
                target.addClass('.fade.out')
                    .html( makeUp ) 
                        ...
                });
```

The **tmp_searcher.cfm** template being loaded contains all search form variants. On initial load I'm grabbing the basic or external(userID) based one.

It's inside tmp_searcher.cfm,  where I cannot access *variables.XXX* anymore... same as URL from my earlier question.... Oh well, writing it down it sort of makes sense, why it's not working ;-)

I spare you the details, first line in tmp_searcher.cfm is:

```
<cfdump output="D:\ColdFusion8\logs\dump.txt" label="catch" var="#variables.user_module#">
```

Which dumps nothing and (@Leigh) throws an error:

```
Element USER_MODULE is undefined in VARIABLES
```

So, my question should have been:

Is there a way for Coldfusion variables to persist through AJAX calls, if the content is on the same page and I'm not wanting to use Session or Application Scope?

Comment: Do not take this the wrong way, but you have really got to start including error messages with your questions (or a description of the wrong results). Because it is not at all clear what "having trouble" means :)

Comment: @Leigh - ok. Next question ;-)

Comment: No time like the present :P Btw, technically what you described should work as is. Included templates have access to the `variables` scope of the calling page. If not, sounds like something else we do not know about is going on :)

Comment: Yes, I can access the `variables` scope just fine when using `cfinclude`. Must be something else going on like in your question about accessing the `url` variable earlier.

Comment: Where are you setting the variables? If your first snippet is inside Application.cfc then you are accessing the CFC's variable scope, not the page's one. Use the Request scope instead.

Comment: Like Peter I suspect your initial snippet is being run in some other scope (like inside a CFC) - or something else is going on in your includes (custom tag call or a CFC) that presents another scope that is not accessible. The code above run as is, with nothing but procedural code inside the included files, *will* work.

Comment: Ok. Thanks all. I think I know what's going on. Same as last question @JasonM... I'm loading shell .cfm pages and then grab the necessary content sections through ajax calls. I'll post an example above.

Comment: In your updated question, you don't need cfoutput around your cfscript. You're not outputting anything. Not sure if that's what's causing your error.

Comment: wait, I see your code now... you're expecting to get a variable in a completely different request.  When you call $.ajax, that's a brand new request... nothing from your current page or any other page is fed into it. It knows nothing but that it's being called. It's almost like opening it in a new browser window by itself. If tmp_searcher.cfm needs to know something, you need to pass it via POST or url vars.

Comment: Yes, I think that's the problem. I thought the varaibles scope was for a page, no matter what I did with it (Ajax in/out content). Sort of like document.live() or document.on() in Jquery

Comment: <cfoutput><head></cfoutput> is unnecessary.  Replace with <head>.

Comment: @ScottJibben: I'm setting <cfsetting enablecfoutputonly="true"> to remove all whitespace. How about then?

Comment: @frequent: Good point, in that case you have to leave the <cfoutput> tags in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the request scope. That will let you access any variables in the request, including the templates.

But the way I use to do it was to use cfimport with a prefix like.. "ui"

```
<cfimport taglib="templates" prefix="ui">
<ui:tmp_pagetop heyLookAVar="#myvar# >
```

Then inside your template you have access to `attributes.heyLookAVar`

You can get really fancy and detect if the template calling tag is ending or beginning... then you only need one

```
<ui:page>
   my page
</ui:page>
```

Comment: ah. so request.someVar? Cool. Didn't know that! THANKS!